# Zend Framework load plugin

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am trying to load a Plugin but I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Class
>   'Site_Plugin_ViewSetup' not found in
>   C:\dev\library\Zend\Application\Resource\Frontcontroller.php
>   on line 92

I configured the file (last line):

```
[production]
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../lib"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts"
resources.frontController.plugins.viewsetup = "Site_Plugin_ViewSetup"
```

And in \lib\Site\Plugin I have ViewSetup.php

```
class Site_Plugin_ViewSetup extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{ ... }
```

I looked at zend docs but could not fid how to properly load a plugin. Does it have to be in the 'library' directory or could I place the 'plugin' folder in the same directory where my 'views' and 'controllers' folders are.

**UPDATE**
I added autoloaderNamespaces and it worked.

> autoloaderNamespaces[] = "site"
>   resources.frontController.plugins.viewsetup
>   = "site_Plugin_ViewSetup"

I don't get why it worked since I already had "site_" in class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you can add this line to your ini:
`autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Site_"`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just put it in the `Site/Plugin/ViewSetup.php` file in your library.